# Camel AtlasMap UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: apache-camel, atlasmap

I'm test driving atlasmap in a camel route. I have created a very simple test input xml file, an adm file, and a route. I get an exception.

```
public class ImportRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from(file("/edi/test/test_file_origin/").include("^.*\\.xml$"))
                .autoStartup(true)
                .to(
                        atlasmap("mapping/xml_to_json.adm")
                )
                .to(log("Done"));
    }
}
```

[image: atlasmap_test]

`test.xml` @ '"/edi/test/test_file_origin/"':

```
<test>
    <id>3</id>
</test>
```

My exception:

```
io.atlasmap.api.AtlasException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (class io.atlasmap.v2.DataSourceMetadata), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "documentType", "documentId", "name", "inspectionType", "dataSourceType", "isSource", "source", "inspectionParameters"])
 at [Source: (GZIPInputStream); line: 1, column: 2083] (through reference chain: io.atlasmap.v2.ADMDigest["exportMeta"]->java.lang.Object[][0]->io.atlasmap.v2.DataSourceMetadata["id"])
    at io.atlasmap.core.ADMArchiveHandler.getDataSourceMetadataMap(ADMArchiveHandler.java:327)
    at io.atlasmap.core.DefaultAtlasContext.<init>(DefaultAtlasContext.java:119)
    at io.atlasmap.core.DefaultAtlasContextFactory.createContext(DefaultAtlasContextFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.atlasmap.AtlasMapEndpoint.getOrCreateAtlasContext(AtlasMapEndpoint.java:253)
    at org.apache.camel.component.atlasmap.AtlasMapEndpoint.onExchange(AtlasMapEndpoint.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:169)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:312)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:483)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:237)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (class io.atlasmap.v2.DataSourceMetadata), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "documentType", "documentId", "name", "inspectionType", "dataSourceType", "isSource", "source", "inspectionParameters"])
 at [Source: (GZIPInputStream); line: 1, column: 2083] (through reference chain: io.atlasmap.v2.ADMDigest["exportMeta"]->java.lang.Object[][0]->io.atlasmap.v2.DataSourceMetadata["id"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:855)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1212)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1604)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1582)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:299)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:293)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3505)
    at io.atlasmap.core.ADMArchiveHandler.getDataSourceMetadataMap(ADMArchiveHandler.java:315)
```

Is Jackson possibly configured incorrectly somewhere else in the project? Ultimately, I want to map the json output of the adm file to a Java object, which I would persist via JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a version mismatch, make sure you're using the same version of AtlasMap UI with the one used by camel-atlasmap component.

Comment: ```<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-atlasmap-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
    </dependency>```